# How can I determine whether an user is connecting from intranet or internet

Tags: javascript, java, angular, networking

I have an application in angular, and backend java.

I've been asked to verify wheter the user that is loggin in, is login from the internet, or the internal network where the app is deployed. 
This is done because I have to restrict the acces to certain users so they can only log in when in the internal network, and I have no idea how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: url to access is same for both ?

Comment: Yes, sadly it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you can use **Ip address**.
I think intranet address range differ from internet IP address. 
You can have a check , if IP range is in intranet one then it's intranet else it a internet request.

Intranet range of IP :

```
0.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255` (10.0.0.0/8, former Class A)

172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255` (172.16.0.0/12, former Class B)

192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255` (192.168.0.0/24, former Class C)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the header of the request, you can look at the "origin".